# Visual Studio 2015 - configuring a custom build batch file

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, visual-studio-2015

I did this in Sublime Text Editor before, and wanted to know if it's possible in Visual Studio: I have a custom build.bat file with this content:

```
@echo off
mkdir w:\project\build
pushd w:\project\build
cl /Zi w:\project\code\win32_project.cpp user32.lib gdi32.lib
popd
```

Is there a way to integrate this into visual studio? Because currently, every time I want to test my program, I have to switch to the file explorer and run build.bat, then switch back to Visual Studio and click on "Start". Not a very ideal solution. The best would be if either I had a shortcut in Visual Studio I could press that'd run this file, or every time I clicked on Start it'd automatically run it for me. Are any of these doable?

Comment: Why don't you just create a project in visual studio instead of the external build of this single file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your batch file as part of a post build step.

In the project propertry pages open the build events tab and add your steps you wish to execute.

[See here for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx)